# Joda Time creating Different Time when parsed

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using the following conversion to convert my Date time from a Millisecond range to a time range with second.

```
DateTimeFormatter f1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
DateTime dt = fmtDateMilliSecs.f1(var1);
var2 = dt.toString(fmtDate);
```

However this code also makes some additional changes in the timestamps. It is converting every value like:

**(Corresponding to Var1)**

```
t1=2015-07-20T00:00:00.000Z
t2=2015-08-19T00:00:00.000Z
```

to 
**(Corresponding to Var2)**

```
t1=2015-07-19T17:00:00Z
t2=2015-08-18T17:00:00Z
```

while it should have converted them to

```
t1=2015-07-20T00:00:00Z
t2=2015-08-19T00:00:00Z
```

I have no idea what i am missing in my date conversions. Can someone help pls ?

Comment: can you please show `var1` and `var2`content or provide a [sscc](http://sscce.org/) or a demo at https://ideone.com/ ?? ;)

Comment: Seems you're missing timezone

Comment: @JordiCastilla updated question

Comment: @SashaSalauyou can you suggest how to fix this ? and if you are really sure ? I am already using Z in my converted value.

Comment: please, read my comment again.... you're not providing enough information to reproduce the error, either enough to fix it...

Comment: @CodeMonkey `dt.toString()` outputs in local timezone, while incoming string is parsed as UTC, that's why resulting value is shifted by 7 hours (your local timezone is `UTC-07:00` I suppose).

Comment: You are using `fmtDateMilliSecs`, `fmtDate`, `t1` and `t2` without specifying where they got they values, and you produce `var2` but don't ask anything about it. It's hard to work with code where you don't even know what the types and values of the things you work with are.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer:

```
DateTimeFormatter f1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```